# XL6009 and isolated output

Tags: converter, isolated

I want to make an isolated DC to AC power supply, with the XL6009 circuit, and I don't know what role "Cdc" have in the circuit. Can I take it off?
My power supply is powered at 5v DC and at the output i need 3v AC ~ 100 mA.

[XL6009 DS](https://www.haoyuelectronics.com/Attachment/XL6009/XL6009-DC-DC-Converter-Datasheet.pdf)

[image]

Comment: NB: There are 2 Cdc capacitors ...

Comment: The capacitor is marked with an arrow.

Comment: I have tried simulating the "same" topology. It appears that the 2 capacitors make "current" through inductors L1C & L1B more triangular.

Answer (score 2):

> I want to make an isolated DC to AC power supply
> at the output i need 3v AC ~ 100 mA

Not really the function of XL6009 ...

The 2 capacitors labeled Cdc are very "useful" for the function implemented.

Here is a simulation for the "same" topology ...
See the different behavior. Shown are voltages outputs and inductors currents.

The duty cycle used: 0.5 to 0.7.

For the "goal" you need, some others components should be taken off.

[image]

[image]

And when one Cdc is disconnected ...

[image]

[image]

EDIT: with some components deleted.
NB: The feedback on the positive output would slightly change the results.
To be tested really with a resistor load.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thx!Can you help me with a scheme that works properly with XL6009?

Comment: What do you need really at the outputs? What kind of waveform?

Comment: I want to power the VFD display filament. I don't think the waveform matters as much as it is AC.

Comment: Do you want making something as this? https://www.instructables.com/A-Simple-Driver-for-VFD-Displays/#:~:text=The%20Filament%20(heater)%20of%20a,to%2030V%20or%20even%20more.

Comment: Yes ( this ic have softstart and is easy to find ).

Comment: I added another picture with results when D1 & Cout are also taken off. You should try with a load resistor to see what rms voltage you can measure with these "conditions" ...

Comment: Thnx! .........